# Android voice command custom

Tags: android, command, voice

My question is regarding custom voice commands for Android.

Is there a way to develop an app, not necessarily a UI app, that adds custom voice commands to any Android mobile?

For example, after installing AccuWeather on Android, every time I ask Google Now for the weather, it displays information fetched from the said app.

1. Did AccuWeather added new voice commands to my phone?
2. Can any app developed by anyone add custom voice commands to an
   Android phone?
3. Can I write and install an app that, triggered by the voice command
   "How is my portfolio?", fetches data from the stock market, returns it
   and then be displayed in the same view, the Google Now view?

I Googled all of these concerns but found more questions than answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can write an app that registers itself as a choice for the available [system commands](https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/system/#system_actions_reference%20%22system%20commands%22.).

As of this writing, you can **not** register an app that registers a [custom command](https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/custom-actions%20%22custom%20action%22.).  Google used to accept requests to register custom voice actions, but stopped.  I don't know why they stopped, or if/when they'll allow customization again.

Answer (score 0):

BTW there was a possibility with an XPOSED Module to add custom commands to google search ( and so you can use the voice recognition even with a smart watch connected ), but it stopped working since they updated the google search app.

if you are just doing this for personal use u can still use it with an old version of google search app and this xposed framework module and correct hooks ( they postet the correct hooks for some updated versions of google app  later in the thread , just use the latest one...).

here you go:
https://forum.xda-developers.com/xposed/modules/mod-google-search-api-t2554173

i really hope google will bring out a better voice API than the actual is.